# Trying to reorder components in React with Framer Motion without parent scrolling

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, reorderable-list

I have a list of items and i need to animate reordering with code. Something like this:

```
<ul className="max-h-[450px] overflow-auto">
  {items.map(item => (
    <motion.li
      key={item.id}
      layout
    >
      <Item onActivate={handleActivate} {...item} />
    </motion.li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Item component is just a simple button with `onClick={onActivate}`

`onActivate` reorders some components with `.sort()` and animation works great. Reordered items slides to new position as expected, but parent `<ul>` element scrolls to top and i don't know how to stop it. I want it to stay in exact same scroll position as it was before reordering. I've tried to change `overflow-auto` to `overflow-hidden` or `overflow-clip` while it was animating, but it makes no difference